# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using the latest MVC framework and bundles.

The default "jqueryval" bundle that MVC creates is causing a javascript error

The scripts on my page are output like so

```
<!-- In head -->
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Misc.js"></script>


<!-- Bottom of doc -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

My Bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
         "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
         "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: If order is a problem, create a bundle per script file and load them in the code in the order you want.

Comment: I thought that may have been it, but when manually putting in it makes no difference

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but did you actually include **jQuery** on your page as well? It seems to be referring to the object being undefined, and that object should be jQuery.

Comment: Yes :D Dumb questions appreciated (you never know!) lol

Comment: Can you post all of JS references from your HTML output. You might be missing something else.

Comment: It looks like the correct files aren't being output. Don't you need `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` (in that order)? Why is `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` being output? I think `validate.unobtrusive` needs `validate`

Comment: Fair point, if you look at my updated answer though shouldnt the Bundle be outputting those too?

Comment: Thats it! Somehow the files were lost during a recent merge! THanks

Comment: @Chris Hmm yeah it seems so (I have like no actual experience with .NET bundling, by the way). I guess my point is that the problem is that the correct JS files aren't being outputted, so the `validate.unobtrusive` file doesn't have the code it needs. So it's not a problem of order - it's a problem of getting the right files in the bundle. I'll see what I can find. You might want to change your question to address this problem, so others may be able to help better

Comment: @Chris Awesome, glad we got to the bottom of it! I added an answer to summarize what we found :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your bundle, you set it to include `jquery.validate*` and `jquery.unobtrusive*`, which would normally work. But if you look at your output, not all files that should be there are there. The point is that `jquery.unobtrusive.validate` requires `jquery.validate` to be included (which, as you can see, is not, by your output). Apparently, the files aren't actually available in your project, and therefore aren't found by the bundler. Make sure to have all necessary files in your project so your bundler can find them and output them.

Answer (score 0):

I found that replacing the wildcards with full js script name worked.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
            ));
```